# Filtering id based on condition

Tags: r, database, filtering, subset, data-manipulation

I have data set with Ids for example
19878, 19659, 19855, 18658, 18996, 18002

I want to filter the IDs based on the number in ID. For example, I want to filter data with ID having 9 in number two position of ID i.e. 19878, 19659, 19855 etc.

Comment: Are you asking how to use a WHERE clause or are you asking how to manipulate the ID in a specific way?

Comment: I want to filter the data based on IDs having 9 in number two position i.e. 19XXX. And want to ignore the data with ID having 8 in position number two 18XXX

Comment: The format of your dataset is not at all clear. Can you post sample data in `dput` format? Please edit **the question** with the output of `dput(df)`. Or, if it is too big with the output of `dput(head(df, 20))`. (`df` is the name of your dataset.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did that by selecting the ID less than or equal to 19000 to separate IDs with 9in second position. 
xam8=exam[exam[,1]<19000,]   ##### selection of 8
exam9=exam[exam[,1]>19000,]   ##### selection of 9

But the answers posted here are useful if specific IDS are needed from whole random data

Answer (score 1):

try this :

```
data <- c(19878, 19659, 19855, 18658, 18996, 18002)
```

Extract your 2nd position of each ID in "data" with substr() :

```
substr(data,2,2)

[1] "9" "9" "9" "8" "8" "8"
```

Find out with grepl() which IDs contain a 9 at the 2nd position :

```
grepl(9,substr(data,2,2))

[1]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Cross your result with your "data" object :

```
data[grepl(9,substr(data,2,2))]

[1] 19878 19659 19855
```

Edit :
Faster solution by Gregor (removing grepl step):

```
data[substr(data,2,2) == "9"]
```

Comment: Nice answer, though since you're looking for an exact match `grepl` is overkill and will slow things down. You can mitigate by using `grepl(..., fixed = TRUE)` or fix entirely by replacing `grepl` with simply `substr(data,2,2) == "9"`.